# c# webbrowser Clicar em um botão utilizando o atributo onclick. getAttribute("onclick") não funciona

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Olá, estou querendo clicar em um botão que têm o seguinte html:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="ExecutarLance('46368');" title="ExecutarLance" class="btn btn-custom3">LANCE</a> == $0
```

Porém o único atributo que eu posso utilizar é o onclick, ele é único deste botão, pois no site existem mais botões com o mesmo href, title e class. Seu eu utilizar o href, o title ou o class o click será em mais de um botão ao mesmo tempo, porque utiliza os mesmos atributos.
Eu consigo fazer o click utilizando o title, o código seria:

```
HtmlElementCollection elementButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement elementyButton in elementButton)
{
 if (elementyButton.GetAttribute("title") == "ExecutarLance")
 {
  elementyButton.InvokeMember("click");
 }
}
```

Porém se eu utilizar este código, o click será em todos os botões que tem aquele title, e são muitos, e eu só quero clicar neste botão específico.
Utilizando a mesma lógica do código anterior porém mudando o atributo title para o atributo onclick (que é único do botão) o código seria:

```
HtmlElementCollection elementButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement elementyButton in elementButton)
{
 if (elementyButton.GetAttribute("onclick") == "ExecutarLance('46368');")
 {
  elementyButton.InvokeMember("click");
 }
}
```

Mas não funciona.

Comment: você não pode simplesmente invocar a function `ExecutarLance('46368')`?

Comment: Com o invokescript?